# Android Room error ProductDatabase_Impl is not abstract and does not override abstract method getProductDao() in ProductDatabase

Tags: android, kotlin, overriding, android-room, dao

I have implemented RoomDatabase in my project using Kotlin. I keep getting the following error.

```
error: ProductDatabase_Impl is not abstract and does not override abstract method getProductDao() 
in ProductDatabase
public final class ProductDatabase_Impl extends ProductDatabase {
```

Here is my Dao interface and ProductDatabase:

```
@Dao
interface ProductDao {

@Insert
suspend fun insertProduct(product: Product) : Long

@Insert
suspend fun insertAll(products: ArrayList<Product>) : List<Long>

@Update
suspend fun updateProduct(product: Product) : Int

@Query("SELECT * FROM product_table")
fun getAllProducts() : LiveData<List<Product>>
}


@Database(entities = [Product::class], version = 1)
abstract class ProductDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

abstract fun productDao(): ProductDao
abstract val productDao: ProductDao

companion object {..//Initialising..}
```

I have used dao in fragment:

```
val dao = ProductDatabase.getInstance(requireContext().applicationContext).productDao()
    repository = ProductRepository(dao)
    val factory = ProductViewModelFactory(repository)
```

I did search about it but mostly what I found is to use kapt instead of annotationProcessor, but I have used kapt from the beginning and other things didn't work. Here are my Room dependencies.

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$roomVersion"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion"
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$roomVersion"
kapt "androidx.room:room-ktx:$roomVersion"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$roomVersion"
```

Answer (score 5):

Well apparently I created a package named `interface` and it was detected as a directory in Android Studio. I kept the dao in that package and that's why the compiler couldn't find the dao interface. Error resolved by removing dao from that directory.